# Convert a MultiDiGraph to MultiGraph without losing existing edges

Tags: python, graph, networkx, edges

I am using OSMnx to return roadmaps, which are represented as MultiDiGraphs in networkx.

```
import osmnx as ox
%matplotlib inline
sg = ox.graph_from_point((37.7936516, -122.4503161), distance=100, network_type='all_private')
ox.plot_graph(sg)
```

[image]

This returns a graph of five nodes (blue dots) connected by six edges (gray).

You'll notice that two nodes have two edges connecting them (in the lower right).  So if you look at `sg[a][b]` you'll get a different edge than `sg[b][a]`.  But if you pull `sg[c][d]` there is not always a `sg[d][c]` (because of one-way roads).

I'd like to convert this to a MultiGraph, so I run `sg_u = sg.to_undirected()` which creates the missing `sg[d][c]`.  But unfortunately it also overwrites existing "reverse" edges.

It's easy to see if looking at the 'length' attributes:

`sg[65283442][65283457]` has a length of 85.36 (m, presumably)

`sg[65283457][65283442]` has a length of only 41.62

But after running `to_undirected()` both have lengths of 41.62.

Is there anyway to simply add the new "reverse" edge rather than redefine it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OSMnx has a built-in function [get_undirected](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.save_load.get_undirected) to handle the quirks of converted a MultiDiGraph of a street network to a MultiGraph.

```
import osmnx as ox
%matplotlib inline
sg = ox.graph_from_point((37.7936516, -122.4503161), distance=100, network_type='all_private')
sgu = ox.get_undirected(sg)
print(sgu[65283457][65283442])
```

Prints:

```
{0: {'from': 65283442,
  'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x1a0c10b67b8>,
  'highway': 'residential',
  'length': 85.36240139096256,
  'oneway': True,
  'osmid': 8915222,
  'to': 65283457},
 1: {'from': 65283457,
  'geometry': <shapely.geometry.linestring.LineString at 0x1a0c10b64a8>,
  'highway': 'residential',
  'length': 41.620571785809716,
  'oneway': True,
  'osmid': 8915224,
  'to': 65283442}}
```

`sgu` is a MultiGraph. As you can see, it retains two (ie, parallel) undirected edges between these nodes and all of the attributes of each.

Also, yes, the OSMnx graph edge lengths are [in meters](https://osmnx.readthedocs.io/en/stable/osmnx.html#osmnx.core.add_edge_lengths) by default.